# List all HTTP request on the webpage (Django)

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, http, request

I am working on project where I need to create separate page with all http requests coming through website. I have created the middle-ware which stores all request in database and the demo-page which displays the list of latest 50 requests.
I need this demo-page to be dynamically updated as soon as new request comes. I played around AJAX but got stuck creating infinite loops at the end.
Any ideas or hints how to do this in the best way?

**Update (there is a progress):**
This is how I did middle-ware to collect only non-AJAX request to avoid infinite-loop. My database is updating on with all other HTTP request except AJAX checker (code is below).

Middle-ware class:

```
# Middleware that stores http requests to the database
class HttprequestMiddleware(object):

def process_request(self, request):
    htpr = [request.method, request.path_info,\
    request.META['HTTP_HOST'],\
    request.META['SERVER_PORT'],\
    request.META['SERVER_NAME'],\
    request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],\
    request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'],\
    request.META['REMOTE_HOST']]
    if request.is_ajax() is not True:
        q = Requestbase(req=htpr, req_date=timezone.now())
        q.save()
```

And the AJAX request:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function refresh() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/mypage/requestview/",
        success: function(update) {
            $("body").html(update);
        }
    });  
}; 
setInterval(refresh(), 5000);
})
```

Now it works, but I am not very much comfortable with continuous `setInterval()` and planning to access the DB, check if quantity of records changed and only after that refresh the DOM.

Please advise.

Comment: You need to show the code you have so far and state where it went wrong.

Comment: You can also use websocket to display realtime request , with ajax you need to call with some interval

Comment: also storing all requests in DB might not work so well once you get more traffic. something like redis will be much better suited for that task

Comment: The AJAX way you went is the easiest way to do this. Please provide more information on how you created an infinite loop.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks, posted edit;

Comment: @SanjaySinalkar SetInterval makes me bothered due to high load. Concern is described in post. Thank you